Transforming a data.table in R and assigning Scores Based on Start and End Positions
I have a data.table df in R with four columns: id, start, end, score. The start and end range from 1 to 10 and id might have duplicates. I would like to transform this data.table into a new matrix B where each row corresponds to an id, and has 10 columns corresponding to each position from 1 to 10. If a position is within the start and end in df for a particular id, the corresponding cell in B should be the score, otherwise it should be 0.
eg:
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2), start = c(1, 5, 1), end = c(3, 7, 2), score = c(10, 20, 30))

df
  id start end score
1  1     1   3    10
2  1     5   7    20
3  2     1   2    30

Expected output：
id  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   10  10  10  0   20  20  20  0   0   0
2   30  30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0


First extending the data's existing score by row, then adding the missing rows and finally transpose.
library(data.table)

Range <- 1:10

df[,.(id, Seq = seq(start, end, 1), score), by = seq_along(id)][
  , transpose(.(sapply(Range, \(x) 
                  max(fifelse(x == Seq, score, 0))))), by = id]
      id    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1    10    10    10     0    20    20    20     0     0     0
2:     2    30    30     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


One possible way to solve your problem:
df[, Map(\(x,y,z) fifelse(1:10 %in% x:y, z, NA), start, end, score) |> 
     c(0) |> 
     fcoalesce() |> 
     as.list(), 
   by = id]

      id    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     1    10    10    10     0    20    20    20     0     0     0
2:     2    30    30     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


Hi, Can you tell me why both you and @Andre Wildberg chose fifelse instead of "felse?

I prefer fifelse over ifelse mainly because it's more robust (and faster). To understand why it is robust check out the examples in its help page by running ?fifelse. Alternatively, you can just run example("fifelse") from the console.

Some related examples are here.  Non-equi joins work well for this.
